# Win32 API : User Impersonation technique to run a process as some other user?

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I'm writing an application which runs a third-party executable as some less privileged user
on Windows. I used following Win32 API functions for this:

```
LogonUser(L"UserName", L"Domain", NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken)
```

then calling

```
CreateProcessAsUser()
```

using hToken I've got to run the process. My actual program which launches this executable is running as Administrator. My doubts here are:

1. If UAC(User Account Control) is enabled. Will this work??
2. I need to create the processes many times. Can I use the `hToken` by
   saving it        somewhere.
3. Does
       `CreateProcessAsUser()` works with different combinations of
       Domain\User  i.e .\Administrator or \Administrator or
       Domain\UserName etc..??

Comment: Try it yourself. `LogonUser` does return restricted token for interactive sessions, but it's not perfectly clear how much of it is restricted. As for #2, you can duplicate the token whenever you're spawning a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx): "Generally, it is best to use [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) to create a process with alternate credentials." The following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx) demonstrates how to call this function.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <userenv.h>

void DisplayError(LPWSTR pszAPI)
{
    LPVOID lpvMessageBuffer;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL, GetLastError(), 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        (LPWSTR)&lpvMessageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    //
    //... now display this string
    //
    wprintf(L"ERROR: API        = %s.\n", pszAPI);
    wprintf(L"       error code = %d.\n", GetLastError());
    wprintf(L"       message    = %s.\n", (LPWSTR)lpvMessageBuffer);

    //
    // Free the buffer allocated by the system
    //
    LocalFree(lpvMessageBuffer);

    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}

void wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    DWORD     dwSize;
    HANDLE    hToken;
    LPVOID    lpvEnv;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    STARTUPINFO         si = {0};
    WCHAR               szUserProfile[256] = L"";

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        wprintf(L"Usage: %s [user@domain] [password] [cmd]", argv[0]);
        wprintf(L"\n\n");
        return;
    }

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!LogonUser(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
        DisplayError(L"LogonUser");

    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpvEnv, hToken, TRUE))
        DisplayError(L"CreateEnvironmentBlock");

    dwSize = sizeof(szUserProfile)/sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (!GetUserProfileDirectory(hToken, szUserProfile, &dwSize))
        DisplayError(L"GetUserProfileDirectory");

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!CreateProcessWithLogonW(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], 
            LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, argv[3], 
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpvEnv, szUserProfile, 
            &si, &pi))
        DisplayError(L"CreateProcessWithLogonW");

    if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpvEnv))
        DisplayError(L"DestroyEnvironmentBlock");

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```